# Is there any way to download an (unpulished) APK from the Google Play dashboard?

Tags: android, google-play, apk

A teammate put the APK in the wrong account in Google Play, now, I need to fix without the original binary.  So, I want to know if I can download the APK out of the wrong account, then signon with the correct account and upload?

FWIW - the APK is not yet published, it is still a draft as we need to put the remaining required collateral from Marketing team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot download the API from the dashboard.  Probably would be some sort of a security violation if it were allowed.

Answer (score 0):

remove APK from wrong account draft.
create APK with correct account signature and upload there.

Comment: not a bad answer, but not the solution I needed for this question.  my unfortunate situation (was) that I did not have a copy of the APK to perform the operation that you suggest in your answer.  Your answer is what the other Developer (who has the APK) did to resolve -- I was trying to resolve while he was asleep in another time zone.  Honestly, I believe the answer to my original question is, "No, you cannot download the APK from the dashboard.  It is only a one-way function uploading."

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a re-marketing ploy (app rustling). It takes an app from one account and replaces the branding (names, images, etc)  with that of another account.

If your devs do not archive their published works, then they are silly persons.  What do they use for a code repository? A sock?

Google only stores the latest version of an app apk. Previous app versions are tracked, but the previous apks are not archived (as far as puny humans are concerned).

Only the latest published apk can be downloaded, and only as a customer.

There is no [Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/) for android apps, [afaik](http://www.subtraction.com/2011/07/25/the-wayback-machine-for-apps/).